How to fine tunning for QuestPDF to generate template
I am trying to generate a PDF in my Blazor Server application. I created the PDF the way I wanted, but I need help editing some areas. I am using the latest version of QuestPDF.
Here is the original template I am trying to generate:

Here is what I did so far:


How can I make it look like the original sample?

The content in sections 1 and 2 in the original PDF can be changed by the user dynamically in the front end.
There might be more data in the grid. (between 1 - 100 for example)

How can I make this template adapt to these conditions? I need your help and guidance to make this template.
Here is the working code:
public class ProformaInvoiceDocument : IDocument
{
    public static Image LogoImage { get; } = Image.FromFile("wwwroot/css/images/logo.png");

    public ProformaInvoice Model { get; }

    public ProformaInvoiceDocument(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public DocumentMetadata GetMetadata() => DocumentMetadata.Default;
    public DocumentSettings GetSettings() => DocumentSettings.Default;

    public void Compose(IDocumentContainer container)
    {
        container.Page(page =>
        {
            page.Size(PageSizes.A4.Landscape());
            page.Margin(1, Unit.Centimetre);
            page.PageColor(Colors.White);
            page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(9));

            page.Header().Component(new InvoiceHeader(LogoImage));
            page.Content().Component(new InvoiceContent(Model));
            page.Footer().Component(new InvoiceFooter(Model));
        });

    }
}

public class InvoiceHeader : IComponent
{

    private readonly Image LogoImage;

    public InvoiceHeader(Image logoImage)
    {
        LogoImage = logoImage;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Row(row =>
        {

            row.ConstantItem(170).Image(LogoImage);


        });
    }
}

public class InvoiceContent : IComponent
{
    private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;


    public InvoiceContent(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;

    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.PaddingVertical(40).Column(column =>
        {
            // Add a line 
            column.Item().PaddingTop(5).PaddingBottom(25).LineHorizontal(1).LineColor(Colors.Grey.Medium);

            //column.Spacing(5);

            column.Item().Row(row =>
            {
                row.RelativeItem().Component(new InvoiceContentRow31(Model));
                row.ConstantItem(1);
                row.RelativeItem().Component(new InvoiceContentRow32(Model));
                row.ConstantItem(1);
                row.RelativeItem().Component(new InvoiceContentRow33(Model));
            });

            column.Item().PaddingTop(25).Element(ComposeRow4);

            column.Item().Component(new TotalsSection(Model));

            column.Item().PaddingTop(20).Component(new NotesSection(Model.SalesContract));


        });


        void ComposeRow4(IContainer container)
        {

            container.Table(table =>
                {
                    // step 1
                    table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.ConstantColumn(25);
                        columns.RelativeColumn(3);
                        columns.RelativeColumn();
                        columns.RelativeColumn();
                        columns.RelativeColumn();
                    });

                    // step 2
                    table.Header(header =>
                    {
                        header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text("#");
                        header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text("Product");
                        header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text("Unit price");
                        header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text("Quantity");
                        header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text("Total");

                        static IContainer CellStyle(IContainer container)
                        {
                            return container.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.SemiBold()).PaddingVertical(5).BorderBottom(1).BorderColor(Colors.Black);
                        }
                    });

                    // step 3
                    foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                    {
                        table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text(Model.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1);
                        table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text(item.Description);
                        table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");
                        table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text(item.ManufacturerCode);
                        table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");

                        static IContainer CellStyle(IContainer container)
                        {
                            return container.BorderBottom(1).BorderColor(Colors.Grey.Lighten2).PaddingVertical(5);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }


    }
}

public class InvoiceContentRow31 : IComponent
{
    private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;

    public InvoiceContentRow31(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.ShowEntire().Column(column =>
        {
            column.Spacing(2);

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Invoice No: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.InvoiceNumber}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Date: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.InvoiceDate:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Customer: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerName}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Address: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerAddress}");
            });


        });
    }
}

public class InvoiceContentRow32 : IComponent
{
    private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;

    public InvoiceContentRow32(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.ShowEntire().Column(column =>
        {
            column.Spacing(2);

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Invoice No: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.InvoiceNumber}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Date: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.InvoiceDate:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Customer: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerName}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Address: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerAddress}");
            });


        });
    }
}

public class InvoiceContentRow33 : IComponent
{
    private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;

    public InvoiceContentRow33(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.ShowEntire().Column(column =>
        {
            column.Spacing(2);

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Invoice No: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.InvoiceNumber}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Date: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.InvoiceDate:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Customer: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerName}");
            });

            column.Item().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span("Address: ").Bold();
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerAddress}");
            });


        });
    }
}

public class InvoiceFooter : IComponent
{
    private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;

    public InvoiceFooter(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.ShowEntire().Column(column =>
        {
            // Add a line
            column.Item().PaddingTop(10).LineHorizontal(1).LineColor(Colors.Grey.Medium);

            column.Spacing(2);

            column.Item().AlignCenter().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerAddress}");
            });

            column.Item().AlignCenter().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span($"{Model.Telephone}");
            });


        });
    }
}

